# A distribution of order k+1 is sum of two.

Tags: distribution-theory

Let $\lambda$ be a compactly supported distribution of order $k+1$ then how to prove $\lambda=\delta'+\mu$ for some compactly supported distributions of order $k$?

Comment: I assume with $\delta'$ you do not mean $(\text{Dirac }\delta)'$, but just some distribution $\delta$ of order $k$?

Comment: Yes, of course $\delta$ is just a general distribution not a Dirac measure.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda \in \def\E{\mathcal E}\E'(\def\R{\mathbb R}\R)$ of order $k+1$. Given any $\varphi \in \E(\R)$, define $\bar\varphi \in \E(\R)$ by $\bar\varphi(t) = \int_0^t \varphi(s)\, ds$. Let 
$$ \delta(\varphi) = -\lambda(\bar\varphi) $$
Then $\delta$ is of order $k$, as 
$$ \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}
\let\phi\varphi\abs{\delta(\phi)} = \abs{\lambda(\bar\varphi)} \le C\norm{\bar\varphi}_{k+1} \le C\norm{\varphi}_{k}. $$
Moreover we have 
$$ \delta'(\phi)
= -\delta(\phi') 
= \lambda(\overline{\phi'})
= \lambda\bigl(\phi -\phi(0)\bigr) 
= \lambda(\phi) - \phi(0) \cdot \lambda(1). $$
That is, if we let $\mu(\phi) = \phi(0) \cdot \lambda(1)$, then $\lambda = \delta' + \mu$.

Comment: I am convinced in your arguments except one little detail. How do we establish $\delta$ and $\mu$ compactly supported?

Comment: $\delta$ is defined on $\mathcal E(\mathbb R)$, hence compactly supported and $\mu$ has the support $\{0\}$.

Comment: And, how $\mu$ is of order $k$?

Comment: What is $\lambda(1)$? You know $1$ is not a test function.

Comment: I mean, how do you do this step: $\lambda(\phi-\phi(0))=\lambda(\phi)-\phi(0)\lambda(1)$?

Comment: @ martini: Could you please reply me regarding my weakness of understanding your arguments which I wrote above?

Thanks!

Comment: @Algebra $1\in\mathcal{E}$ on which $\lambda$ is defined. And $\mu$ is some Dirac $\delta$, so of order $0$.

Comment: You mean if supp$(\lambda)=K$ then $1=\chi_{K}$ but then $\chi_{K}$ is not a test function.

Comment: @Algebra Every distribution $T$ with compact support is uniquely extendable to $\mathcal{E}$ [basically by choosing a test function $f$ which is 1 on a neighbourhood of the support of $T$ and to consider the distribution $(fT)$ and this does not depend on the special choice of $f$.]

Comment: How does this inequality hold $C\norm{\bar\varphi}_{k+1} \le C\norm{\varphi}_{k}$? It should be other way, right? Then how do we establish the result?

Comment: @Algebra $(\bar{\varphi})'(x) = \varphi(x)$, so $||\bar{\varphi}||_{k+1} = \max\{||\varphi||_k, ||\bar{\varphi}||_{0}\} \leq ||\varphi||_k (1+\text{measure}(\text{supp}(\lambda))$.